# Allow dashes in email validations

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this email validation regex

`[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\+\\\\.\\\\_\\\\%\\\\-\\\\+']{1,256}[\\\\@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\\\-]{0,64}([\\\\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\\\-]{0,25})+`

but it won't allow for emails like asd-asd@gmail.com ... i.e. using "-". I can't figure out how to make it work. Any ideas ?

Comment: Try this: `^[\\w+.'%-]{1,256}@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,64}([.][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,25})+$`

Comment: ``\\\\`` inside character class `[...]` represents single ``\`` literal, not escape sequence. So ``\\\\-\\\\`` is like `a-a` range, in other words it also represents only ``\`` character. Use ``\\`` instead of ``\\\\`` if you want to use it as escape sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just append `-` in the first square brackets.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\+\\\\.\\\\_\\\\%\\\\-\\\\+'-]
                                         ▲
```

This will ensure that dashes are allowed as well.

Comment: Is there a "full" email validation regex out there? Initially I got an issue with apostrophes ' ... now with dashes ... :( sigh

Comment: @AndreiBogdan Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) related?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `-` to the part before the `@`.

The full regex then looks like this:
`[a-zA-Z0-9\\\\+\\\\.\\\\_\\\\%\\\\-\\\\+'\-]{1,256}[\\\\@]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\\\-]{0,64}([\\\\.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\\\\-]{0,25})+`

Comment: `-` placed at the end of `]` doesn't need to be escaped since it doesn't create a range, so it is not considered as metacharacter. Also you would need two ``\`` before it in Java string literals.

Comment: @Pshemo Thank you for the comment. You're right; I edited my answer and removed the escape sequence now.

Comment: I was referring to ``\`` in `'\-]`. You don't need it, but even if you did it would need to be written as `'\\-]` if it was meant to be as escape sequence for regex.